# Delete Post Meta with Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove duplicate meta_values from a table where the duplicate values share the same post_id.  An import went wrong and there's several hundred thousand rows with a lot of duplicate values.

So in the example below there are two rows with post_id 12 and meta_value of 6 when there should only be one.

```
meta_id    post_id    meta_key               meta_value
-------    -------    --------               ----------
1          12         attribute_pa_length    6
2          12         attribute_pa_length    6
3          12         attribute_pa_length    9
4          35         attribute_pa_length    8
5          35         attribute_pa_length    12
```

Comment: which one you want delete `meta_id = 1` or `meta_id = 2` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will leave you with the smaller `meta_id`

```
DELETE T1
FROM YourTable T1, YourTable T2
WHERE T1.post_id = T2.post_id   
  AND T1.meta_value = T2.meta_value
  AND T1.meta_id > T2.meta_id
```

Comment: Thanks, just the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Just remember if you want keep the biggest `meta_id` just change `> for <`